# Difference between Octane render and Eevee render?

Tags: add-on, eevee-render-engine, octane-render-engine

I am blender beginner. I found Blender has 2 renders, eevee and cycle. But I also find an Octane render in website. What are the differences among eevee, cycle and octane? Is octane an addon? Is yes, how much?

Comment: There is also Redshift, Thea, LuxCoreRender etc. Related: [What's the purpose of the EEVEE rendering engine?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79568/whats-the-purpose-of-the-eevee-rendering-engine)

Answer (score -1):

Well, yes and no. Octane is not for blender only, it's more of an engine in many 3d software. https://render.otoy.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=72241#p366488, Octane uses the computer GPU to render, and it is like Cycles but a real-time raytracing, which means its acts like evee but produces renders like cycles. Evee is just a real time render engine 
which doesn't care about light that much.

Comment: So if I focus on npr stylised shading, eevee or octane render? And is octane render free addon? Thank you

Comment: If you focus on PBR then go for cycles, eevee is an shady character at that, octane is not that much of a build for blender, but it is available for 2.8 version.in windows only, you can check it here https://www.blendernation.com/2019/09/26/blender-2-8-beginner-tutorial-free-octane-render-and-first-impressions-addons/